# python pandas rolling apply custom function is returning a keyError

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to apply a custom function to a rolling window but it gives a KeyError and I'm not sure why or how to fix it. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744746/follow-up-rolling-apply-depreciated) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe), but the answers didn't solve the issue.

Here is my code to reproduce the error:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

def return_chi2(df):                                                               
    return chi2(df['signal'].to_numpy().reshape(len(df['signal'].index),1), 
        df['PnL_binary'].to_numpy().reshape(len(df['PnL_binary'].index),1))[1][0]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['signal'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
df['PnL_binary'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

return_chi2(df)
>>>0.04953461343562649
```

So far so good, the function works and returns a chi-squared. The issue is applying it to a rolling window:

```
df.rolling(3).apply(return_chi2)

    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'signal'
```

I believe the error is related to the apply function attempting to look for 'signal' as an index value rather than a column. I tried:

```
df.rolling(3).apply(return_chi2, axis=1) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Not really sure where to go from here? I could use something like iterrows and roll through the whole df manually slicing the window but it doesn't seem very pythonic - there should be a better way to do this? Would appreciate any help to get this going?

Comment: `type(df.rolling(3))` → `pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling`, which expects an aggregation.

Comment: The docs here suggest that I should be able to use a rolling apply method but they don't provide an example: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html